# Task Exception Null in Chained C# Task Continuation

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have a `C#` application which executes a method that returns a [Task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx). In this case, I'm trying to show a message box containing the exception details if the called method throws an exception.

If I call it like this, I can see the exception fine in `task.Exception`:

```
MyClass.MyAsyncMethod(cancellationToken)
       .LogExceptions()
       .ContinueWith(task => {
           MessageBox.Show(task.Exception);
       }, cancellationToken, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

However, if I add an `OnlyOnRanToCompletion` continuation, `task.Exception` in the `NotOnRanToCompletion` continuation becomes null:

```
MyClass.MyAsyncMethod(cancellationToken)
       .LogExceptions()
       .ContinueWith(task => {
           Log.Info("Executed");
       }, cancellationToken, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.Default)
       .ContinueWith(task => {
           MessageBox.Show(task.Exception);
       }, cancellationToken, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion, TaskScheduler.Default);
```

**The code in the `OnlyOnranToCompletion` continuation is not executed, but the code in the `NotOnRanToCompletion` continuation is executed and `task.Exception` is null. Why does this happen?**

Note: I cannot use `C# >= 5.0` features like `async` or `await`. I'm also able to get around this by having it all under a single `None` continuation method that checks the exception parameter of the task and determines if an exception occured. However, I'm interested in WHY the above behaviour takes place.

---

This is the called method:

```
public Task<bool> MyAsyncMethod(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return Task<bool>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        ...

        try
        {
            var response = request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK) 
                throw new Exception("Invalid response status code: " + response.StatusCode);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Error("Request failed", ex));
            throw;
        }
    }, cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default);
}
```

Comment: Note that the fact that error handling is so difficult and tedious is a big reason why `await` was added, as it *greatly* simplifies proper error handling.

Comment: Agreed, though in my case upgrading to a newer version is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no exception because the `Task` that it is a continuation of didn't throw an exception.  The `Task` that it is a continuation of (the previous call to `ContinueWith`) will have completed successfully.

If you want to handle both the error and non-error case, you're probably better off just having one continuation and checking if it was successful in that continuation, rather than using the continuation options.  Alternatively you could store the `Task` from the actual work that you're doing and add both continuations as continuations to that one `Task`, rather than having one continuation being a continuation of the other.

Comment: Now that makes perfect sense. Thank you!